# Magento - Categories do not show properly in catalog

Tags: php, css, magento

I'm using Magento 1.81 with Codewix category accordion menu extension.

The code: 
    class Codewix_Leftmenu_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
    {

```
 protected $_leftCategories;

/**
 * top level parent category for current category
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $_parent;

protected function _construct()
{
    $path = $this->getCurrentCategoryPath();
    $parent = $path[count($path)-1];
    if (!$parent) {
        $parent = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    }
    $this->_parent = $parent;
}

public function getBlockTitle() {

}

public $curr_class ="main-categ";

public function  get_categories($categories) {
        $i=0;

        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

        if($i==0) {
        $ul_id="outer_ul";

        } else {
        $ul_id="inner_ul";
        }
    $array= '<ul id="'.$ul_id.'" class="'.$this->curr_class.'">';
     $this->i++;
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
     if($category->getId() != 1) {
            if($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
                $this->curr_class = "current";

                } else {
                $this->curr_class = "main-categ";
                }
            if($category->hasChildren()) {

            } else {


            }
        $array .= '<li id="big-categ" style="background-color: red;">'.'<label class="'.$class.'">'.'<a href="'.$helper->getCategoryUrl($category).'">'.$category->getName()."</a> (".$cat->getProductCount().")</label>" . '</li>';
    }
        if($category->hasChildren()) {

            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
             $array .= '<li id="small-categ" style="  visibility: visible;">' . $this->get_categories($children) . '</li>';
            }
         $array .= '</li>';

}
    return  $array . '</ul>';


}
```

}

outputs the following

[image]

and i want to output just

[image]

without CSS business (visibility / display)

Thanks!

Comment: make css for using this ul > li > ul  and ul > li > ul >li possible to add your url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should edit the .phtml file that displays the accordian and where it has something like

```
echo($this->get_Categories($someArrayofAllTopLevelCategories));
```

Change it to

```
$myParticularChildCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories([put here the integer ID of the Rochii category]);
echo($this->getCategories($myParticularChildCategories));
```